# Hosting Large web app - databases

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, hosting

I am learning about hosting this days (still planning phase of the project). I can develop my app in php or asp.net. In hosting options I saw: Databases - 'mssql - Unlimited x 200 MB'. What does this mean? Is it when my users fill 200 mb I must start using another db? I don't know how this works, all I know is I need large space (for over 1.000.000 users). I never hosted large app so I don't know exactly where to look.

Comment: @110 , is it personal or you are working in some company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 mb is the database size, once you reach that you will need to upgrade your database with that host or migrate to a different host.

200 mb sounds quite small for 1 million users.

```
200*1024*1024/1000000 = 209.7 bytes per user.
```

Ignoring overheads and assuming 1 byte per character that's 209 alphanumeric characters per user, which is probably not gonna be enough to store a profile let alone anything useful.

If you're aiming at 1,000,000 users and know what your database structure is going to be like you can do a rough calculation to tell you how much space you require.

for example, a basic user table consisting of

```
username - nvarchar(20)
email    - nvarchar(100)
password - nvarchar(20)
```

nvarchar is unicode so 2 bytes per character + 2 byte overhead

so worst case storage is

```
42+202+42 == 286 bytes per user
* 1,000,000 == 286,000,000
/(1024*1024) = 272.75 MB
```

This ignores indices which will be necessary on a table that size, and at only one table isnt a very useful database.  Naturally if you have a better idea of the space taken up by an average entry in each table you can calculate based on that.

See this msdn article for more info on [Estimating the Size of a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187445.aspx)

That said, one million users is a hell of a lot, a smaller host may well suffice you while your developing your userbase.

Comment: Because I am more familiar with asp.net I think it would be better to develop app with it. If I understand, I can use that small database hosting until I get too much users and then transfer project to another host. I do some search and what I saw is that all hosting companies offer 200 mb options. And maybe I should later use dedicated hosting, but how much that scaling might cost (compare to oss solutions)?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to talk with your shared host company or any host company and ask it's pre-sales department.

If you want to store binary data (files, images, videos) on your database, then, perhaps those 200MB will be of no use.

If you want to store 1.000.000 users informations like "Name, birth date and a few more, then, 200MB will be ok).

The host disk space and the bandwidth considering those users, should be your biggest concern.

Hope it help you somehow.